# How t set FieldType.USER in sharepoint file property with Java - Invalid data has been used to update the list item

Tags: java, sharepoint, custom-field-type, fieldtype

I'm trying o use method CopyIntoItems and add to uploaded file owner property. Field Owner should be type USER. am setting up it like this:

```
            FieldInformation fieldInformationUser = new FieldInformation();
            fieldInformationUser.setDisplayName("Owner");
            fieldInformationUser.setInternalName("Owner");
            fieldInformationUser.setType(FieldType.USER);
            fieldInformationUser.setValue("domain//username");
```

I'm using this library: [Sharepoint library link](https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/)
If TEXT type field is updated in presented above way - it passes, but does't update field at SharePoint server. Problem occurs when i'm using type USER - server returns 
**Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.**

WSDL specifies fieldType.USER as a string field. he question is, how this string should look like... Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the user exists in the users table in SharePoint. It may be that it exists in AD but it hasn't been added to SharePoint yet.

If it were C#, then you would first issue the EnsureUser command:

```
//C# CSOM code
SPUser user=web.EnsureUser(userName);
listItem[fieldName] = user;
```

You should search for a similar method in the library you're using